# Disabling timezone adjustments of jackson in a spring-integration application

Tags: java, jackson, timezone, spring-integration

I'm deserialzing JSON in a spring integration application like this:

```
<int:json-to-object-transformer type="com.something.domain.Transaction[]" />
```

This is generally working well, apart from handling dates.

The annotaded class contains the following:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
@JsonProperty("clickDate")
private Date clickDate;
```

The date is parsed without error, but testing revealed that jackson does make timezone adjustments. E.g. if the JSON contains the date "2018-02-15T11:43:00", the deserializer converts it to the equivalent of "2018-02-15T12:43:00" (one hour difference).

Is it possible to disable these adjustments, so that the original date is deserialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson will by default parse a `Date` using UTC timezone which will not modify the time. Confirm that Jackson's timezone hasn't been modified. E.g. if `mapper` is the `ObjectMapper`

```
System.out.println(mapper.getDeserializationConfig().getTimeZone());
```

you can then set the timezone with [setTimeZone](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-)

If it proves impossible to modify Jackson's timezome settings you can override them for a field by specifying a timezone in `@JsonFormat` annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
            pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
            timezone = "UTC")
Date clickDate;
```

Comment: I've tried the @JsonFormat timezone annotation suggested, but compared to the input string the timezone is still changed.

Comment: After lots of trail and error, this was the correct solution after all. The mistake I made was to convert the Date to a String using the SimpleDateFormat, but not setting a TimeZone on the SimpleDateFormat. That's why it looked as if jackson used the wrong time zone, which it didn't do.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean so far about *disabling*, but if it is even possible, you can do that via:

```
<xsd:attribute name="object-mapper" use="optional">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Optional reference to a JsonObjectMapper instance.
                By default, a JsonObjectMapper that uses a Jackson 2 ObjectMapper.
            </xsd:documentation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                    <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.integration.support.json.JsonObjectMapper" />
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

and use:

```
public Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
```

with the customized `ObjectMapper` from Jackson.

By default Spring Integration uses this one:

```
public Jackson2JsonObjectMapper() {
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    this.objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    this.objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable();
}
```

where that `registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable()` stands for these modules:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk7.Jdk7Module
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule
com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
```

So, maybe even one of those time-based module can help you without any modifications.

Comment: This sounds interesting. How would you add a custom ObjectMapper in Spring XML configuration? (I didn't mention it explicitly, but as can be seen in the cited code in the question I'm using classic XML style approach).

Comment: ??? I show you an `object-mapper` attribute of the `<json-to-object-transformer>`. The IDE must suggest you such one.

Comment: I see, so that is what you meant. I'd like to try this, but I'm stuck with Spring Integration 4.x which doesn't seem to register these modules.

Comment: Right, that is there really since `5.0`. But you still can configure your own `ObjectMapper` with all those modules and inject it into the `<int:json-to-object-transformer>` via `Jackson2JsonObjectMapper` anyway